# How to use redux with graphql

Tags: redux, graphql, apollo

I like graphql. Because it has a single endpoint and I can only pull out the data I need.

So I use apollo-server for the server and apollo-client for the client.

Starting with apollo-client 3.0, state-management is supported.

The reactive variable function of the apollo-client is very convenient, but I prefer redux.

Redux toolkit also shortened the length of code that needs to be written.

The question is this.

1. Can't I use apollo-client 3.0 and redux together?
2. Can't I just use graphql without an apollo-client on redux? then How?

check please!

Comment: use Apollo client [with **normalizing cache**] for all fetched data (copying/duplicating data to redux doesn't make sense, managing fetching/waiting/error handling, too) ... redux for other, global app state (drawer open, active filter, [default] sorting order, etc.) common/consumed in many places/components

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's important to understand that [GraphQL is just a protocol for describing requests and responses](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/11/how-web-apps-work-ajax-apis-data/#graphql).  However, yes, "I'm using GraphQL" typically also implies using a smart client library like Apollo or Urql.

It is certainly possible to use Apollo and Redux in the same app, but the question becomes what you're using each of them *for*.  I've covered this in my posts [When (and when not) to Reach for Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/03/redux-not-dead-yet/) and [Redux - Not Dead Yet!](https://changelog.com/posts/when-and-when-not-to-reach-for-redux).  Summarizing:

- You can use Redux for anything, including server state caching and client-side state
- Apollo is purpose-built for caching server state with GraphQL requests
- If the *only* thing you were using Redux for was caching server state, and you choose to use Apollo for that task, you really don't need Redux any more
- But, you can use GraphQL for requests and put that data in Redux if you really want to

It's worth noting that we have [an "RTK Query" API for Redux Toolkit that provides a complete data fetching abstraction](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview), and [we even have a demo of using RTK Query to request and cache data with GraphQL](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#react-with-graphql).  You may want to try that out.

Comment: The second link points to an empty sandbox. Do you know of a RTK/GraphQL example I could check?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote that before we had released RTKQ, so those pointed to preview branches. Just updated the links to point to our current docs and examples.